# Null Value in Union Query With Filter Column

Tags: sql-server

I Create SQL Query To Calc Items Quantity
The problem : I Want View All Items When I Select From The Query By StorageID
When Excute Data From Query It view The Items That Have a Transactions With Numbers In & Out and Other Items have Null Values In All Fields

This is My Query

```html
Select
PurchaseInvoice.StorID AS StoID,
PurchaseInvoice.DocDate AS DocDate,
PurchaseInvoice.DocTrans AS DocTrans,
items.SupplierID as SupID,
Items.GroupID AS GroupID,
Items.SeasonID As SeaID,
P.ItemCode AS ItemCode,
P.ItemName AS ItemName,
P.Price AS Price,
P.Qty AS QtyIN,
0 AS QtyOut
From PurchaseInvoice2 P
INNER JOIN PurchaseInvoice ON P.DocID=PurchaseInvoice.DocID
INNER JOIN Items ON P.ItemCode=Items.itemcode
UNION
Select
PurchaseInvoice3.StorID AS StoID,
PurchaseInvoice3.DocDate AS DocDate,
PurchaseInvoice3.DocTrans AS DocTrans,
items.SupplierID as SupID,
Items.GroupID AS GroupID,
Items.SeasonID As SeaID,
PP.ItemCode AS ItemCode,
PP.ItemName AS ItemName,
PP.Price AS Price,
0 AS QtyIN,
PP.Qty AS QtyOut
From PurchaseInvoice4 PP
INNER JOIN PurchaseInvoice3 ON PP.DocID=PurchaseInvoice3.DocID
INNER JOIN Items ON PP.ItemCode=Items.itemcode
UNION
Select
SalesInvoice.StorageID AS StoID,
SalesInvoice.DocDate AS DocDate,
SalesInvoice.DocTrans AS DocTrans,
items.SupplierID as SupID,
Items.GroupID AS GroupID,
Items.SeasonID As SeaID,
S.ItemCode AS ItemCode,
S.ItemName AS ItemName,
S.Price AS Price,
0 AS QtyIN,
S.Qty AS QtyOut
From SalesInvoice2 S
INNER JOIN SalesInvoice ON S.DocID=SalesInvoice.DocID
INNER JOIN Items ON S.ItemCode=Items.itemcode
UNION
Select
SalesInvoice3.StorageID AS StoID,
SalesInvoice3.DocDate AS DocDate,
SalesInvoice3.DocTrans AS DocTrans,
items.SupplierID as SupID,
Items.GroupID AS GroupID,
Items.SeasonID As SeaID,
SS.ItemCode AS ItemCode,
SS.ItemName AS ItemName,
SS.Price AS Price,
SS.Qty AS QtyIN,
0 AS QtyOut
From SalesInvoice4 SS
INNER JOIN SalesInvoice3 ON SS.DocID=SalesInvoice3.DocID
INNER JOIN Items ON SS.ItemCode=Items.itemcode
UNION
Select
StorageIN.StorageID AS StoID,
StorageIN.DocDate AS DocDate,
StorageIN.DocTrans AS DocTrans,
Items.SupplierID as SupID,
Items.GroupID AS GroupID,
Items.SeasonID As SeaID,
STIN.ItemCode AS ItemCode,
STIN.ItemName AS ItemName,
STIN.PurchasePrice AS Price,
STIN.Qty AS QtyIN,
0 AS QtyOut
From StorageIN2 STIN
INNER JOIN StorageIN ON STIN.DocID=StorageIN.DocID
INNER JOIN Items ON STIN.ItemCode=Items.itemcode
UNION
Select
StorageMortal.StorageID AS StoID,
StorageMortal.DocDate AS DocDate,
StorageMortal.DocTrans AS DocTrans,
Items.SupplierID as SupID,
Items.GroupID AS GroupID,
Items.SeasonID As SeaID,
SMR.ItemCode AS ItemCode,
SMR.ItemName AS ItemName,
SMR.PurchasePrice AS Price,
0 AS QtyIN,
SMR.Qty AS QtyOut
From StorageMortal2 SMR
INNER JOIN StorageMortal ON SMR.DocID=StorageMortal.DocID
INNER JOIN Items ON SMR.ItemCode=Items.itemcode
UNION
Select
StorageOut.StorageID AS StoID,
StorageOut.DocDate AS DocDate,
StorageOut.DocTrans AS DocTrans,
Items.SupplierID as SupID,
Items.GroupID AS GroupID,
Items.SeasonID As SeaID,
SO2.ItemCode AS ItemCode,
SO2.ItemName AS ItemName,
SO2.PurchasePrice AS Price,
0 AS QtyIN,
SO2.Qty AS QtyOut
From StorageOut2 SO2
INNER JOIN StorageOut ON SO2.DocID=StorageOut.DocID
INNER JOIN Items ON SO2.ItemCode=Items.itemcode
UNION
Select
StorageStart.StorageID AS StoID,
StorageStart.DocDate AS DocDate,
StorageStart.DocTrans AS DocTrans,
Items.SupplierID as SupID,
Items.GroupID AS GroupID,
Items.SeasonID As SeaID,
SST2.ItemCode AS ItemCode,
SST2.ItemName AS ItemName,
SST2.PurchasePrice AS Price,
SST2.Qty AS QtyIN,
0 AS QtyOut
From StorageStart2 SST2
INNER JOIN StorageStart ON SST2.DocID=StorageStart.DocID
INNER JOIN Items ON SST2.ItemCode=Items.itemcode
UNION
Select
StorageStart.StorageID AS StoID,
StorageStart.DocDate AS DocDate,
StorageStart.DocTrans AS DocTrans,
Items.SupplierID as SupID,
Items.GroupID AS GroupID,
Items.SeasonID As SeaID,
SST2.ItemCode AS ItemCode,
SST2.ItemName AS ItemName,
SST2.PurchasePrice AS Price,
SST2.Qty AS QtyIN,
0 AS QtyOut
From StorageStart2 SST2
INNER JOIN StorageStart ON SST2.DocID=StorageStart.DocID
INNER JOIN Items ON SST2.ItemCode=Items.itemcode
UNION
Select
StoragesTrans1.FromS AS StoID,
StoragesTrans1.DocDate AS DocDate,
StoragesTrans1.DocTrans AS DocTrans,
Items.SupplierID as SupID,
Items.GroupID AS GroupID,
Items.SeasonID As SeaID,
STT2.ItemCode AS ItemCode,
STT2.ItemName AS ItemName,
STT2.PurchasePrice AS Price,
0 AS QtyIN,
STT2.Qty AS QtyOut
From StoragesTrans2 STT2
INNER JOIN StoragesTrans1 ON STT2.DocID=StoragesTrans1.DocID
INNER JOIN Items ON STT2.ItemCode=Items.itemcode
UNION
Select
StoragesTrans1.ToS AS StoID,
StoragesTrans1.DocDate AS DocDate,
StoragesTrans1.DocTrans AS DocTrans,
Items.SupplierID as SupID,
Items.GroupID AS GroupID,
Items.SeasonID As SeaID,
STT22.ItemCode AS ItemCode,
STT22.ItemName AS ItemName,
STT22.PurchasePrice AS Price,
STT22.Qty AS QtyIN,
0 AS QtyOut
From StoragesTrans2 STT22
INNER JOIN StoragesTrans1 ON STT22.DocID=StoragesTrans1.DocID
INNER JOIN Items ON STT22.ItemCode=Items.itemcode
```

I need Help With This

Comment: Any Help Please ?

Comment: Can you show sample data and what the expected results you want?

Comment: my query View Only Items That have Transaction in Other Tables
i need my query to view all items have or haven't transaction
---- My Condition on select from query ( StorageID ) .

Comment: Maybe use interpuntion so your question is readable